# A way to express 100 by using the first four natural numbers

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Is there a way to express 100 by using the first four natural numbers in order?

The numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 can be linked by using $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, $($ $)$, $!$ and exponents are also allowed.
But you are not allowed to leave the integers.

Examples: $$-1+(2+3)^4=624$$ $$(1!+2)^{3^4}= large$$

Comment: Brute force is likely applicable for this kind of problem, just list all possibilities using a computer...

Comment: Can you explain your first example? I evaluate the left hand side to be $624$. Also, what is the : operator?

Comment: @PC1 you are absolutly right.

Comment: @JohnDouma  I would guess $:$ is division so $\div$ or $/$

Comment: @JohnDouma Henry is right.

Comment: Do you have to use all $1,2,3,4$ ?

Comment: If Sigma is in play we can get some answers such as 50 with ease, for example: $$\sum_{n=1}^4 (2+3)n$$

Comment: Is concatenation accepted? That is, would $12+3^4=93$ be a valid expression?

Comment: $(1+(-2+3!)!)\cdot 4=100$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems more like a Puzzling.SE question to me but here's a CW post for others to edit. 79/100 complete

| Number | Expression |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | $-1+2\cdot3-4$ |
| 2 | $1+2+3-4$ |
| 3 | $1+2\cdot3-4$ |
| 4 | $1+2-3+4$ |
| 5 | $1^{2\cdot3}+4$ |
| 6 | $1-2+3+4$ |
| 7 | $-1+2\cdot3!-4$ |
| 8 | $-1+2+3+4$ |
| 9 | $1\cdot2+3+4$ |
| 10 | $1+2+3+4$ |
| 11 | $1-2+3\cdot4$ |
| 12 | $1^2\cdot3\cdot4$ |
| 13 | $1+2+3!+4$ |
| 14 | $1\cdot(2+3\cdot4)$ |
| 15 | $-(1+2)!-3+4!$ |
| 16 | $-1\cdot2^3+4!$ |
| 17 | $1-2^3+4!$ |
| 18 | $-1\cdot2\cdot3+4!$ |
| 19 | $-1 + (2+3)\cdot 4$ |
| 20 | $(-1+2+3)!-4$ |
| 21 | $-(1+2)!+3+4!$ |
| 22 | $-(-1^2+3)!+4!$ |
| 23 | $-(1^{2\cdot3})+4!$ |
| 24 | $-1-2+3+4!$ |
| 25 | $-(1\cdot2)+3+4!$ |
| 26 | $1-2+3+4!$ |
| 27 | $-1-2+3!+4!$ |
| 28 | $-1+2+3+4!$ |
| 29 | $1-2+3!+4!$ |
| 30 | $1+2+3+4!$ |
| 31 | $-1+2+3!+4!$ |
| 32 | $1\cdot2^3+4!$ |
| 33 | $1+2+3!+4!$ |
| 34 |  |
| 35 | $-1+2!\cdot3!+4!$ |
| 36 | $1\cdot2!\cdot3!+4!$ |
| 37 | $1+2!\cdot3!+4!$ |
| 38 |  |
| 39 | $-1+2^{3!}-4!$ |
| 40 | $ (1+2)! \cdot 3! +4$ |
| 41 | $1+2^{3!}-4!$ |
| 42 | $(1+2)!\cdot(3+4)$ |
| 43 | $1+2\cdot(-3+4!)$ |
| 44 | $(-1+2\cdot3!)\cdot4$ |
| 45 |  |
| 46 |  |
| 47 | $-1+2\cdot3!\cdot4$ |
| 48 | $(1^2+3)!+4!$ |
| 49 | $1+2\cdot3!\cdot4$ |
| 50 |  |
| 51 | $(1+2)^3+4!$ |
| 52 | $(1+2\cdot3!)\cdot4$ |
| 53 | $-1+2\cdot(3+4!)$ |
| 54 | $(1+2)!^3/4$ |
| 55 | $1+2\cdot(3+4!)$ |
| 56 |  |
| 57 |  |
| 58 |  |
| 59 | $-1+2^{3!}-4$ |
| 60 | $(1+2)!\cdot3!+4!$ |
| 61 | $1+2^{3!}-4$ |
| 62 |  |
| 63 | $(1+2)\cdot(-3+4!)$ |
| 64 |  |
| 65 |  |
| 66 |  |
| 67 | $-1+2^{3!}+4$ |
| 68 | $1\cdot2^{3!}+4$ |
| 69 | $1+2^{3!}+4$ |
| 70 | $-1\cdot2+3\cdot4!$ |
| 71 | $-1^2+3\cdot4!$ |
| 72 | $1^2\cdot3\cdot4!$ |
| 73 | $1^2+3\cdot4!$ |
| 74 | $1\cdot2+3\cdot4!$ |
| 75 | $-(1+2)!+3^4$ |
| 76 |  |
| 77 |  |
| 78 | $-1-2+3^4$ |
| 79 | $-(1\cdot2)+3^4$ |
| 80 | $1-2+3^4$ |
| 81 | $1^2\cdot3^4$ |
| 82 | $-1+2+3^4$ |
| 83 | $1\cdot2+3^4$ |
| 84 | $1+2+3^4$ |
| 85 |  |
| 86 |  |
| 87 | $-1+2^{3!}+4!$ |
| 88 | $1\cdot(2^{3!}+4!)$ |
| 89 | $1+2^{3!}+4!$ |
| 90 | $(1+2)\cdot(3!)!/4!$ |
| 91 |  |
| 92 | $(1-(-2+3!)!)\cdot(-4)$ |
| 93 |  |
| 94 |  |
| 95 | $-1+(2+3)!-4!$ |
| 96 | $1\cdot(2+3)!-4!$ |
| 97 | $1+(2+3)!-4!$ |
| 98 |  |
| 99 |  |
| 100 | $(1+(-2+3!)!)\cdot 4$ |